# I have got struck in a problem where I have the task to update the old line with a new line in a .txt file using C

Tags: c, file, file-writing, file-pointer, fputs

I have opened the file in "r+" mode and tried to use `fputs` to replace old_line (line) with new_line (updated_line)

```
char updated_line[] = "Hello This was ABCD";
fseek(fp, -(strlen(line))-1, SEEK_CUR); 
fputs(updated_line, fp);
```

**Given txt file data :**

```
Hello This is ABCD
Studying in XYZ College
```

**Output:**

```
Hello This was ABCD
udying in XYZ College
```

The two characters "St" are missing from next line. How do I rectify this ?

Comment: You can't just rewrite text in a text-file, unless the new text is *exactly* the same length as the existing text in the file. Instead you basically have to rewrite the whole file. Read it line by line, writing the lines into a new (temporary) file. When you reach the line you want to modify, write the modified line to the new file. Then rename the new file as the old original file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is correct, yet the -1 in `fseek(fp, -(strlen(line))-1, SEEK_CUR);` makes no sense.